# Why doesn't content/code assist work inside html tags in eclipse helios in the jsp editor?

Tags: helios, content-assist, code-assist

It took me a while to isolate where the problem comes up but I've narrowed it down to this:

If I have an html tag in my jsp like so:
">

The content assist won't work for the jsp expression Defs.NAME if it's inside an html tag (ie between <>)

If I do this:
<%=Defs.NAME%>
then the content assist works fine. It just has to be outside the html brackets.

When I say it doesn't work, I mean the box comes up with no suggestions. Whereas 'works fine' means it gets all the suggestions in scope.

Worked fine in ganymede.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in helios that's fixed in sr2.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333784